# How to modify anchor tags in botframework Web chat

Tags: javascript, botframework, web-chat

We've just started using the bot-framework. For client side we are using the cdn and not react. We have certain links that bot responds with. And we would like to append a url parameter to each link and open the link in the same window. So far this is what my code looks like. Is there a better way to achieve this using the botframework. I know there is `cardActionMiddleware` which has `openUrl` cardAction, but we don't have any cards and I am not sure on how to implement that.

```
var webchatMount = document.getElementById('webchatMount');

function loadChatbot() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', "https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'BotConnector ' + '<secret>');
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      var store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, function ({ dispatch }) {
        return function (next) {
          return function (action) {

            if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
              var event = new Event('webchatincomingactivity');
              event.data = action.payload.activity;
              window.dispatchEvent(event);
            }

            return next(action);
          }
        }
      });

      window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
        {
          directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: response }),
          store: store,
        },
        webchatMount
      );
      document.querySelector('.webchat__send-box-text-box__input').focus();
      window.addEventListener('webchatincomingactivity', ({ data }) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
          var links = document.querySelectorAll('#webchatMount a');
          if (links.length >= 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= links.length; i++) {
              if (links[i] == undefined)
                break;

              var compare = new RegExp('maindomain');
              var href = links[i].getAttribute('href');
              var st = getParameterByName('st', href);
              if (links[i].hasAttribute('target')) {
                links[i].removeAttribute('target');
              }

              if (compare.test(href)) {
                // internal link
                // check if it has st=INTRA
                if (st) {
                  console.log(' it has a value');
                } else {
                  links[i].setAttribute('href', insertParam('st', 'INTRA', href));
                }

              } else {
                // external link, do nothing
              }
            }
          }
        }, 1000);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

and here are `getParameterByName` and `insertParam` functions.

```
 function getParameterByName(name, url) {
      name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
      var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
          results = regex.exec(url);
      if (!results) return null;
      if (!results[2]) return '';
      return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  }

  function insertParam(key, value, url) {
        key = encodeURIComponent(key);
        value = encodeURIComponent(value);
        // kvp looks like ['key1=value1', 'key2=value2', ...]
        var kvp = url.split('&');
        var i=0;
        for(; i<kvp.length; i++){
            if (kvp[i].startsWith(key + '=')) {
                var pair = kvp[i].split('=');
                pair[1] = value;
                kvp[i] = pair.join('=');
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i >= kvp.length){
            kvp[kvp.length] = [key,value].join('=');
        }

        return kvp.join('&');
    }
```

I am new to botframework webchat so I don't know it very well. I know that the secret should not be used like that, but for know we are testing and would like to get it to work. Any help would be appericiated

Thanks.

Comment: The method you chose is basically on target. Any suggestions would essentially amount to variations on a theme.

Comment: @StevenKanberg Thanks. We ended up using this approach.